# Implementing D * lite in UE4 for a project

Tags: c++, dynamic, path-finding, unreal-engine4, d-star

I have asked this question on the forums but had no luck so far.

Im a student currently trying to implement dynamic pathfinding for my fyp. Im been working with UE4 for the past few weeks because I decide to try and implement the D * lite pathfinding algorithm in a level.Im wondering is there anyone on here with knowledge on this subject.I dont know where to really look into overwriting ue4 pathfinding with my own attempt. I think it may be in UNavigationComponent but im not certain

I have read the papers of d * lite .Im just not sure how to do this in UE4.

Im using unreal 4.6.1

Thanks for your time and any help you may offer.Have a nice day

Ethan

Comment: Can you show some code attempted? It's ,more likely you will get specific help.

Comment: Hi paisanco..Im not looking for a solution to the implementation as of yet its more of where to start concerning its implementation in UE4..i.e how it will be integrated into a bot.I hope that it makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UE4 comes with its own navigation system based on navmeshes. I do not think that tapping into that system will give you anything you can use for your D* algorithm. Plus, the navigation system is (in my opinion) very poorly documented and obscure.

If you want to do this for a project then just calculate everything you need yourself. Iterate over the actors in the world and get their mesh data to calculate the input for your algorithm. Then visualize the output back into the world e.g. with decals on the ground.

Comment: thanks for the reply :) . I came to that realization recently and decided to just use UE4 navigation to implement AI behaviour  for my project.   I may give what you have suggested a try after I finish this final year project for college.